# Ruby hangs on load using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

Installed ruby 2.4.0 using RVM, but after typing ruby, the command just freezes indefinitely. Can be ctrl-C'ed out, but ruby never loads.

[image]

Ruby info:

```
ruby-2.4.0:

  system:
    uname:        "Linux waffleboy 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    name:         "Ubuntu"
    version:      "16.04"
    architecture: "x86_64"
    bash:         "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:          "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)"
    remote path:  "ubuntu/16.04/x86_64"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.29.2 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "23 minutes 20 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/waffleboy/.rvm"
    autolibs:     "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.4.0p0"
    date:         "2016-12-24"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2016-12-24 revision 57164"
    full_version: "ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0"
    ruby:         "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/home/waffleboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin:/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin:/storage/anaconda3/bin:/home/waffleboy/bin:/home/waffleboy/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/usr/bin:/storage/programfiles/:/home/waffleboy/bin:/storage/programfiles/spark-1.6.2/bin:/home/waffleboy/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0:/home/waffleboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0"
    IRBRC:        "/home/waffleboy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Rvm list:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I've tried reinstalling and installing ruby multiple times but it just doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal; it is a feature, not a bug.

Running `ruby`, without any parameters, causes the program to run and wait to receive input from `STDIN` (ending with an `EOF` character). It will not execute anything until it receives this information.

If you want to run ruby in **interactive** mode, (like when you run `python`), then use ruby's built-in `irb` ("interactive ruby") command.

Alternatively, if you just want to display some basic information about the ruby version installed then you can try commands like:

```
ruby -v # Display version information
ruby -h # Display help about usage, switches and features
```

Comment: Thank you! :) I forgot about that - havent touched ruby in quite a while!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a REPL to type Ruby code into, have it executed, and see the results, then you're looking for the `irb` command, not `ruby`.

`ruby` is for running files (eg. `ruby my_file.rb`), or without arguments will read a script typed into standard input, which will get executed when you quit `ruby` with cmd+D.